# Why the reset is assigned value of start + 1 in cortex m3

Tags: arm, microcontroller, cortex-m, microprocessors

I am learning the assembly language of cortex m3, I don't understand why the reset is start + 1, it should be start only know as to when reset it should execute from start and is there any special reason that sp is assigned 0x200.

```
    .thumb
    .syntax unified

sp: .word 0x200
reset:  .word start +  2

start:
    mov r0, #5
    mov r1, #4
    add r2, r0, r1

stop:   b stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bit of a bug as written in more than one way.  The arm documentation clearly states that vectors are the address with the lsbit set so one can think plus one but it is safer to OR with one.

The cortex-m3 if/when you read up on it, is armv7-m based, and in the armv7-m documentation which you should also have before doing any kind of programming like this then:

> On powerup or reset, the processor uses the entry at offset 0 as the initial value for SP_main, ... All other entries must have bit[0] set to 1

> On exception entry, if bit[0] of the associated vector table entry is set to 0, execution of the first instruction causes an INVSTATE UsageFault

(yes that means all exception vectors not just reset)

Let the language work for you and you won't have to hack at these bits, the tools will do it for you:

```
.thumb
.syntax unified

sp: .word 0x200
reset:  .word start

.thumb_func
start:
    mov r0, #5
    mov r1, #4
    add r2, r0, r1

stop:   b stop
```

Once linked (the table can't be filled in until linked and the linker knows that label is a function so generates the proper value).

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <sp>:
   0:   00000200    andeq   r0, r0, r0, lsl #4

00000004 <reset>:
   4:   00000009    andeq   r0, r0, r9

00000008 <start>:
   8:   f04f 0005   mov.w   r0, #5
   c:   f04f 0104   mov.w   r1, #4
  10:   eb00 0201   add.w   r2, r0, r1

00000014 <stop>:
  14:   e7fe        b.n 14 <stop>
```

And you can see that the vector table is proper and will function, the reset vector points at the reset handler start: ORRed with 1 (0x00000008|1 = 0x00000009)

Comment: Is it necessary that I should assign the stack pointer with value 0x200, or I can assign any other value.

Comment: I would assume never would it be 0x200.  you have to look at the documentation for the chip (arm doesnt make chips, so st, nxp, ti, whatever) and it will tell you where ram is and how much and you choose from there, often it starts at address 0x20000000 so maybe a value like 0x20001000 or however much memory you have.  Or you can do linker things to allocate a chunk of memory for the stack (never made sense to me but YMMV).  0x200 is almost always going to be flash so not read/write sram so cant be used as a stack.

Comment: I simply cut and pasted your code and tweaked the one thing.

Comment: Saying that arm does have recommendations on address space which is why 0x00000000 is flash and sram often starts at 0x20000000 across chip vendors.